# Save multiple checkbox[] check state on page refresh using local storage in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, checkbox

I have problem to show user checkbox check state after page is refreshed. I tried using local storage but it checks all the checkboxes please help!
I have use ajax to load different pages to select the row by checkbox
This is input value

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkselect" data-name="checkselect[]" class="get_value" value="<?php echo $row['car_booking_id'];?>">
```

And this is my javascript

```
   <script>
$('.get_value').on('click', function() {
  var fav, favs = [];
  $('.get_value').each(function() { // run through each of the checkboxes
    fav = {id: $(this).attr('name'), value: $(this).prop('checked')};
    favs.push(fav);
  });
  localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favs));
  alert(fav);

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  //alert(favorites);
  if (!favorites.length) {return};
  console.debug(favorites);

  for (var i=0; i<favorites.length; i++) {
    console.debug(favorites[i].value == 'on');
    $('#' + favorites[i].id ).prop('checked', favorites[i].value);
  }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Is it because all the input elements have the same `id`?

Comment: @ DinoCoderSaurus i have to keep all list in array as checkselect[] so id is same

Answer (score 0):

A simple demo of using a storage object to keep track of which checkboxes have been ticked.

There is a useful factory function here `StoreFactory` I wrote to simplify further working with storage objects - it only has a very few methods and is very simple to use.

The demo generates a number of checkboxes similar to the one you show in the question - though I have made life simpler by adding a unique `dataset.id` attribute - this could easily be the actual id instead but in the question it would appear that multiple checkboxes would share the same ID which is not valid.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <script>
            const StoreFactory=function( name, type ){
                'use strict';
                const engine = type.toLowerCase() === 'local' ? localStorage : sessionStorage;
                const set=function( data ){
                    engine.setItem( name, JSON.stringify( data ) );
                };
                const get=function(){
                    return exists( name ) ? JSON.parse( engine.getItem( name ) ) : false;
                };
                const remove=function(){
                    engine.removeItem( name );
                };
                const exists=function(){
                    return engine.getItem( name )==null ? false : true;
                };
                const create=function(o={}){
                    set(o);
                };
                return Object.freeze({
                    set,
                    get,
                    exists,
                    create,
                    remove
                });
            }



            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e=>{
                /* create a new storefactory object */
                let store=new StoreFactory('favourites','local');

                /* if the actual store does not exist, create it */
                if( !store.exists() )store.create();

                /* get the data stored in the local storage object */
                let data = store.get();


                /* assign event listeners to all the checkboxes */
                Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]') ).forEach( chk=>{
                    chk.addEventListener('click', e=>{

                        /* add checked state to store */
                        data[ e.target.dataset.id ]=e.target.checked;

                        /* save the data */
                        store.set( data );
                    })
                });

                /* reload stored checkboxes */
                Object.keys( data ).map( k =>{
                    if( data[ k ]==true )document.querySelector( 'input[ type="checkbox" ][ data-id="'+k+'" ]' ).checked=true;
                    else {
                        delete data[ k ];
                        store.set( data );
                    }
                })
            })
        </script>
        <style>
            form{ margin:auto; display:flex; flex-diection:row;flex-wrap:wrap; align-items:center;align-content:center;justify:content:center;font-family:cursive }
            label{min-width:4rem;padding:0.5rem;margin:0.25rem;border:1px solid rgba(133,133,133,0.1);box-sizing:border-box;background:whitesmoke}
            label:before{content:attr(data-value);color:blue}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post' name='checkboxes'>
        <?php
            /* some checkboxes - note the use of the dataset id attribute! */
            for( $i=1; $i <= 50; $i++ ){
                printf('<label data-value=%d><input data-id="chk_%d" type="checkbox" name="checkselect[]" value="%d" class="get_value" /></label>', $i, $i, $i );
            }
        ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

There were, as far as I can tell, a few little issues with your code. Not being a user of `jQuery` I might be mistaken but it looks like your get a reference to ALL the checkboxes and, regardless of the checked state, add them to your `favs` array which is then saved in the local storage object. In itself that is fine, the problem revolves around `fav = {id: $(this).attr('name'), value: $(this).prop('checked')};` ~ there would be no way to tell which checkbox is which if there are several checked. Each checkbox would need a unique ID ( as is always true ~ ID attributes MUST be unique!! )

It also seems that the `click` handler should be defined after the `$(document).ready` call and then I guess remove the inline `onchange="CheckedChange(this)"` from each checkbox.

Slightly re-written version of your code which works.. though I don't know the syntax for using the jQuery `data` method... I think I'm close but it was not right so used vanilla js instead.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var favorites = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'favorites' ) );

        $('.get_value').on('click', function() {
            var favs = [];
            $('.get_value').each(function(){
                favs.push( {
                    id:$(this).attr('data-id'), 
                    value:$(this).prop('checked')
                } );
            });
            localStorage.setItem( 'favorites', JSON.stringify( favs ) );
        });

        if( favorites!==null ){
            for( var i=0; i < favorites.length; i++ ) {
                //$('input').data( 'id', favorites[i].id ).prop( 'checked', favorites[i].value );
                if( favorites[i].value ) document.querySelector( 'input[ type="checkbox" ][ data-id="'+favorites[i].id+'" ]' ).checked=true;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have used below code but my form is based on ajax load so whenever new form is loaded the checkbox state is not saved

Comment: that rather changes the nature of the question does it not? Perhaps you ought to add, to the original question, sufficient code to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your html you should add a unique attribute to each checkbox like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkselect" data-name="checkselect[]" 
data-unique="<?php echo $row['car_booking_id'];?>" 
class="get_value" 
value="<?php echo $row['car_booking_id'];?>">
```

Now save the checked status by the unique_id and `$('.get_value[data-unique="' + favorites[i].unique_id + '"]').prop('checked', favorites[i].value);` would get the input that has that attribute and set checked to on or off depending on the stored state

```
$('.get_value').on('click', function() {
  var fav, favs = [];
  $('.get_value').each(function() { // run through each of the checkboxes
    fav = {unique_id: $(this).attr('data-unique'), value: $(this).value};
    favs.push(fav);
  });
  localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favs));
  alert(fav);

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  //alert(favorites);
  if (!favorites.length) {return};
  console.debug(favorites);

  for (var i=0; i<favorites.length; i++) {
    console.debug(favorites[i].value == 'on');
    $('.get_value[data-unique="' + favorites[i].unique_id + '"]').prop('checked', favorites[i].value);

  }
});
```

Let it be clear that it is bad practice to use the `id` attribute to group elements. It is for uniqueness and should be used as such. Grouping element can be done using the `class` or `data-[anything]`  attribute.

I hope this helps